# Compiling error JEE 6 project with Criteria

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a Java EE 6 Project in Netbeans 8.2 running on JDK 1.7u52 which runs fine when I compile and start it in the IDE. However, when I clean and build the project, I am getting the following error :

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type ch.djan.lee.compute.entity.SpaceLog_
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:625)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:554)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:699)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:981)
```

NB : i'm working on Criteria and eclipsLink 2.4

Comment: How many Persistence unit you're using ?

Comment: I've Three PU, but what's the relation of the problem with the Number of persistence unit !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update your persistence.xml file like this :

```
<persistence-unit name="first_PU">
   <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="first"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="second_PU">
   <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="second"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="third_PU">
   <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="third"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And after deploying your project, you'll get :

```
ch.djan.lee.compute.entity.SpaceLog.first 
ch.djan.lee.compute.entity.SpaceLog.second 
ch.djan.lee.compute.entity.SpaceLog.third
```